# Is there a way to read a string from a file that are separated by enter key?

Tags: c

I'm a new programmer, and I learning some C.

The problem is, I got a file that it's words are separated by the enter key, such like:

```
Apple
Banana
Cinnamon
```

I'd like to store all this data in a single variable (a string (array of characters)) but I think that my fgets() function stops when finds an enter key.

So I'd like to know if there's another way to do it

```c
char* readFile(void){ // 

    FILE *text;
    text = fopen("text1.txt", "r");  

    char *words;

    words = malloc (sizeof(char)*10); 

    fgets(words, 2000, text); 

    fclose(text); 

    printf("%s\n", words); // Just to see the output

    return words;

}
```

When I read the file containing:

```
Apple
Banana
Cinnamon
```

The output is:

```
Apple
```

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` is for reading lines in a file.  According to the man page:

> fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

If you want to get raw data, use `fread`.  The man page for that function describes it as:

> The  function  fread() reads nmemb items of data, each size bytes long, from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location given by ptr.

Another option is just calling `fgets` three times for each line, then the input will already be split up.

Which way to go depends on what you want to do with the data.